# Is there a way to set mark and then have characters typed included in the region?

Tags: emacs

I'm wondering if there is a way in Emacs, that allows the user to call set mark(C-SPC) and then continue typing(and have everything typed included in the region) and then copy(M-w) the typed text?

I guess I'm looking for a way to type text and copy the text in one step.

I hope this makes sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C-SPC`, type some text, `M-w` will copy the text you just typed. In Emacs, the region is the area between the mark and the point, it doesn't need to be visible.

Answer (score 4):

The answer by @xuchunyang is almost correct.  And by default it is correct.

But there is actually a user option that controls the behavior, **`mark-even-if-inactive`**. By default it is `t`, but if it's value is `nil` then you will need to use `C-x C-x` (twice, if you want to put point back where it was), in order to activate the region, before you can use `M-w` to copy its text to the `kill-ring`.  `C-h v mark-even-if-inactive` tells you:

> **`mark-even-if-inactive`** is a variable defined in `C source code`.
>
> Its value is `t`
>
> Documentation:
>
> Non-`nil` means you can use the mark even when inactive.
>
> This option makes a difference in Transient Mark mode.
>   When the option is non-`nil`, deactivation of the mark
>   turns off region highlighting, but commands that use the mark
>   behave as if the mark were still active.
>
> You can customize this variable.